# installing software for a newbie

Tags: wine

I'm new to Ubuntu and I want to install wine. It's not in my Ubuntu software centre, but I have downloaded the files from the internet. How do I get it to install from the files I have downloaded?

Comment: The types of files you downloaded (you didn't tell us) dictate how they are installed.  If tarball you .... If a deb you ....  etc, but it's often best to follow the instructions provided wherever you got the software.  Please note: when you install manually, you have to update the packages yourself, and they may become a problem when you next release-upgrade (ie. bump yourself to the next release).  `wine` can be found in the repositories (which avoids all these problems or security concerns) - https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=all&searchon=names&keywords=wine

Comment: "new to Ubuntu"  and "wine" should not be in the same sentence. if you want to use windows stuff install virtualbox and windows into that.